# What is the most bulletproof way of checking a variable is not null or empty?

Tags: php

In PHP, What is the best way to check whether a string variable is empty or null?

I currently have the following:

```
if($variable == null || $variable == "")
    exit;
```

And wondered if there was a more minimalistic way of doing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean [`empty($var)`](http://php.net/empty)?

Comment: How about `if (empty($variable)) { ... }`?

Comment: Don't forget: empty <> null <> 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use empty() see http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

```
if(empty($myvariable)) 
   exit();
```

Empty returns true if the variable is **empty** or **null**, full details below

From the doc

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.
>
> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.

The following things are considered to be **empty** (return true):

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- **NULL**
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Answer (score 3):

```
if (empty($variable))
    exit;
```

You could also use `is_null()` if you wanted to explicitly test whether or not the variable was set to the value `null`.

Comment: Empty does a null check, so the second statement will never be got to!

Comment: Please simply remove the `is_null` check because beginners might read your code but not your comment on it.

Comment: @nkr -- removed. Still, `is_null()` can be useful enough to warrant a mention, in case somebody was unaware such a function existed.

Comment: @ScottS. I agree with you but, in this case, it's better to directly provide the right solution and give additional hints later instead of providing more than necessary first and then narrowing it down to the needed function.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

Comment: Please provide the English version.

Comment: Tip: PHP.net supports short links for function names which automatically redirect to the native language of the visitor. Example: http://php.net/empty

Answer (score 0):

For checking whether a variable is null or empty please refer the below code snippet

```
    if(is_null($variable) || empty($variable))
    {
      exit;
    }
```

For documentation about is_null and empty functions please refer the below urls
http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php